# Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ a non abelian group or order $p^3$. Prove that $Z(G) = [G,G]$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ a non abelian group or order $p^3$. Prove that $Z(G) = [G,G]$.

I have already figured out that $|Z(G)| = p$, and that $G'=[G,G] \lhd G$.

Also, $|G'| = p$ or $p²$.

I suppose I'd have to prove that $G' \subset Z(G)$, but I've been trying and I have no idea how. Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: I think $[G, G]$ is intended instead of $[G:G]$.

Comment: What is meant by $[G:G]$?

Comment: And $[G,G]$ is?

Comment: @Señor Billy: There is a theorem which says the following: if $N$ is normal subgroup of $G$ where $G/N$ is abelian, then $G' \subseteq N$. Since $|G/Z(G)| = p^2$, it follows that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Hint (assuming that with $[G:G]$ you mean $G'=[G,G]$, the commutator subgroup): since $G$ is nilpotent, $G'\ne G$; can $Z(G)$ have index $p$ in $G'$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $G$ is non-abelian group, we should have: $|\frac{G}{Z(G)}|=p^2$. (else, $|\frac{G}{Z(G)}|=p$ and it's mean $G$ is abelian group). Now consider that, every group by order $p^2$ is abelian group (Because if $G$ be a group from order $p^2$. So $|Z(G)|\gt1$. if $|Z(G)|=p$ , then: $|\frac{G}{Z(G)}|=p$ and  $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ should be cyclic. so $G$ should be abelian group. ). Now remember that: if $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, then: $\frac{G}{N}$ is abelian group if and only if: $G'\subseteq N$. So, because of $\frac{G}{Z(G)}$ is abelian, $G'\subseteq Z(G)$